# Pointer is not coming exact position on meter arc while rotation

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my code, everything is working fine except the position of the pointer on meter arc. I just want to place that circular pointer exactly in the middle of the arc while rotation. Currently, it's moving out of arc. Apart from it, I want to remove extra gray line coming at the bottom of the same arc from the left and right side.
Here it was not allowing me to insert full code. Kindly find the whole code in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/shutterwithfocus/pen/Roddwb).

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="credit_score_container">
        <div class="inner_circle">
            <div class="score_meter">
                <div class="control" r=t u=i>
                    <div id="shape"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that your code or you trying to modify someone else's code ?

Comment: @Flying Gambit It's my code only.

Comment: It looks too big to debug, is it possible for you to give us a smaller, easy to read fiddle ?

Comment: @Flying Gambit  Actually i have already given you main part only. I can't reduce any thing from it. If you want I can upload it on dropbox or anywhere and share that link with you.

Comment: No need to do that, its very time consuming, hope someone else comes to your aid

Comment: @sanjay go to Codepen and search for rounded slider, there are a few examples there that have what you need and probably the answer to your question